# me/friends?fields=installed returns some installed = true when have not installed

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have this query:

```
FB.api('/me/friends?fields=installed,name&<?php echo $access_token?>',  { data: response.data }, function(res) {

}
```

But in the response, are few installed attribute it's true when they're not, haven't installed (because i store any registered user in my database and they are not there)

I checking like this:

```
if(response.data.length > 0){
    for(i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++){
       var guy = response.data[i];
       if( guy.installed == true ) { // also tried with ===
          // do stuff
       }
    }
}
```

Is there any better way to check for sure?

PS: Just thinking, this could be because they acept but something failed y my callback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I really got your problem, but I'd trust the FB data more then my own data concerning the `installed` flag. So maybe there's a glitch in storing the people which are using your app in your database?

Secondly, `/me/friends` should AFAIK *only* return those friends which are using your app, so it should be always `true` for those. I did a test with one of my apps, and this seems to be correct.

Thirdly, it should be sufficient to check

```
if (guy.installed) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: No, /me/friends used to return all users friends... Did that change?

Comment: That changed 1,5 years ago!

Comment: I see that... There is no way to get all the friends, then ?

Comment: No, and this has been answered here hundreds of times

Comment: `var fql = encodeURI('SELECT uid, name, pic_square FROM user WHERE uid = me() OR uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())');
  FB.api("/fql?q="+fql+'&<?php echo $access_token?>', function(response) {` ?

Comment: FQL is depracated as well